# How to implement View Model functionality in ASP.net Web Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, textbox

I'm working with an asp.NET web site -- something I'm not used to. I have a page with a ton of `asp:Textbox` controls, all with `runat="server"`, and I have a `DataTable` full of their values. Basically I want to implement some kind of **MVC model-like functionality** so I can assign the values to each `textbox`.

So, a few questions:

> 1. Is there some way to do this in a fairly best-practice manner? (Dont want to use session, etc)
> 2. If not, can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

The general look of one of the `textbox` is this:

```
<asp:Textbox runat="server" class="number" name="ns_loanAmt" id="ns_loanAmt" value="???" />
```

Comment: Have you tried using a codebehind file and putting the logic into page_load?

Comment: @DigitalD Thought about it, but I didn't want to have to manually set each value if I don't have to. That's what I'm going to do if there isn't anything "cleaner" to do, though

Comment: MVC has the power of the built-in modelbinder, plain ASP.net web forms does not.

Comment: @DigitalD That's the problem :P I wanted to kind of implement my own. But I think I may just do what you suggested at first

Comment: Better way - Switch to ASP.NET MVC if you feel that ASP.NET MVC addresses your pain point. Would that be difficult?

Comment: You can add MVC to an existing ASP.Net website and have both ASP.Net & MVC pages in the same site, but that doesn't sound like what you're looking for. It sounds like you want to add MVC-like functionality to an ASP.Net page, which is a bad idea IMO. You might not like the pattern you have to work with, but that IS the pattern. Either convert the page to a real MVC page, or follow @DigitalID's advice of using the code-behind, which is the proper pattern for ASP.Net.

Comment: @Suhas difficult? no, not really. My decision? unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

The question seem to be quite old and for some reason it has been edited so possibly someone could still be interested.

I wonder why the OP hasn't considered the built-int web forms binding. Although nowadays I mostly use MVC, for years we all developed dozens of applications using the ASP.NET data-binding and it surely works.

In this particular case I would create a class that would stand as a model for a single textbox. The class would contain the value, the CSS class, possibly some other properties.

```
public class RowModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string CSSClass { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then I would have a repeater, a gridview or a listview and I would put a textbox in the row template.

```
<asp:ListView ID="listView1" runat="server">
  ...
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox id="textBox" runat="server" 
                  cssclass="<%# CSSClass %>" Text="<%# Text %>" /> 
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Then, in the code behind, I would just bind the list of model instances to the bindable control.

```
List<RowModel> rowList;
...
if ( !this.IsPostBack )
{
   listView1.DataSource = rowList;
   listView1.DataBind();
}
```

or even create an `ObjectDataSource` and bind declaratively.

Then, upon each post back, the list of POSTed values can be read and put back into the database.

ASP.NET Web Forms binding always worked and because of the automatic viewstate management specific scenarios were even much simpler than manual, MVC-like state management. For example, insert and edit templates provided in a listview were easily switchable, something that needs some effort in plain MVC (although you have much, much better control over what happens).